# ffmpeg: select (-map) audio track by codec id

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, codec

How can I use ffmpeg `-map` switch to select the audio track by its codec?

Say there is a video.mkv with one video stream (0) and three audio tracks (1, 2, 3).

The audio tracks have different codecs, say DTS, AAC and AC-3 (in any order).

I want to produce an output file with the video stream `-map 0:0` and **only** the AAC track, something like:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -map 0:0 -map 0:aac -codec copy output_with_aac_audio.mkv
```

In the real scenario I don't know which one is the AAC track (1, 2 or 3).

Comment: I am not sure whether there is a way to map by codec, but at least you can check the index with `ffprobe`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Tom Yan mentioned in his comment you can use `ffprobe` to get the stream indexes:

```
$ ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams a -show_streams -show_entries stream=index,codec_name:tags=:disposition= -of csv input.mkv
stream,1,vorbis
stream,2,aac
stream,3,mp3
```

I'll assume you're using Linux, so adding `awk` will give you just the index(es) of the aac stream(s). In this example the result show the aac stream as stream index `2`:

```
$ ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams a -show_streams -show_entries stream=index,codec_name:tags=:disposition= -of csv input.mkv | awk -F',' '/aac/ {print $2}'
2
```

Then use `-map 0:2` in your `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: I'm on windows. Since ffmpeg can't do it directly (yet) you got the closest. Thanks.